# Autocompletebox - detect 'new' item entered

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, autocomplete

I'm working on a MVVM WPF application, and one of the requested features is an autocompletebox that filteres a selection of items, allowing a user to begin typing an item to quickly find and select the correct one, this is relatively easy to do with autocompletebox.

However there is also the requirement to detect when the user types in a none existing item, and then create that item. However i'm having issues working out how to detect when a user enters text that doesn't match an item.

I attempted to bind to the text property and fire an event when the autocompletebox loses focus, then check to see if the selected property is set if not use the text to create a new item. However this leads to problems if the user enters text, selects and item, and then changes the text to an none existing item.
This leads to both SelectedItem being set and Text being set to something new.

So what i'm after is:

1. Allow user to enter text, and on pressing tab/return select the first match in the list
2. If there is no matching item when the user hits return/tab create a new item with that name

Seems like something that should be pretty obvious/easy as i imagine this is far from uncommon, however I've yet to see a reasonable way of doing this that doesnt require hack code or writing a custom autocompletebox, which i would rather avoid having to do, if anyone knows of an existing control that can achieve this, or a method to do this please.

As requested, here is the code i've used.

View Code:

```
<Utils:AutoCompleteFocusableBox MaxWidth="200" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="5"
          ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsList}"
          IsTextCompletionEnabled="True"
          FilterMode="Contains"                          
          x:Name="ACBox"
          LostFocus="ACBox_LostFocus"                         
          Text="{Binding ItemText, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"                           
          SelectedItem="{Binding ItemInfo, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"/>
```

View Code Behind:

```
private void ACBox_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        AutoCompleteFocusableBox box = sender as AutoCompleteFocusableBox;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(box.SearchText))
        {
            string text = box.SearchText;
            IEventAggregator eventAggregator = IoC.Get<IEventAggregator>();
            eventAggregator.Publish(new SearchTextEvent(text));
        }
    }
```

ViewModel Code:

```
 public string ItemText
    {
        get { return _itemText; }
        set
        {
            _itemText = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => ItemText);
        }
    }

public ItemInfo ItemInfo
        {
            get { return _itemInfo; }
            set 
            {
                if(_itemInfo != value)
                {
                    _itemInfo = value;
                    NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => ItemInfo);
                }
            }
        }
```

Event Handler in ViewModel, and method to check item.

```
public void Handle(SearchTextEvent message)
    {
        CheckItem(message.Text);
    }

    private void CheckItem(string itemName)
    {
        if (ItemInfo == null)
        {
            if (ItemsList.Where(x => x.ItemName == itemName).Count() < 1)
            {
                ItemInfo = new ItemInfo(0, itemName, null);
                NewItemVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
            }
            else
            {
                NewItemVisibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                ItemInfo ii = ItemRepository.GetItemByName(itemName);
                ItemInfo = ii;
            }
        }
        else
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: share some code, how you've tried to solve the same.

Comment: I'm not sure what code you would like, it is all pretty standard, but i shall post anyway

Comment: you can create attachable behaviors for such purpose, that will enable you to have the behavior on regular textboxes too. in this approach you may not require to hard wire the events from view to code behind, everything would be plug and play, can be set via styles etc.